# Cloned a firebase app and changed project, I get this with Google Sign In: "Invalid Idp Responde: access_token audience is not for this project"

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-signin

I made a Firebase project with a mail and managed to get Google Sign In working with Firebase Authentication. I cloned that app folder, changed the Firebase account and project, changed all the names of the google_services.json, and a lot of stuff, but I get this with Google Sign In:
"Invalid Idp Responde: access_token audience is not for this project"

I have been trying to fix this for 2 days straight, searching old questions and methods, asking an AI for I don't know how long but I can't get to fix it.
Btw the normal Email+Password login does work with FirebaseAuth. I only get this with google_sign_in.

I tried to log in with Google from Firebase Authentication like the other app did.

I expected it to work since this is a copy from a project where it works.

What happened is an error that is pretty direct, but still can't fix it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And is it for Android, iOS, or the web?

Comment: So far I tried to change the firebase console, change the SHA-1, check the access_token, all seems to work, is for android, but I'm trying on the web before making the apk to try on my phone. I have the working project too and everything seems fine here too. I just need to find stuff that I left from one project to the other but can't see it

Comment: In that case, maybe this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).

Comment: Yeah that's great, but not what I need right now, my code works and did work in the past correctly and I dont wanna change that, I only need to fix the access token error that pops up with no reason. When I press the google sign in, my account appears and then the error appears.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct JSON file in your project?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the one that appears in Firebase, I literally downloads it from the android app and put it in android/app. Now, I think I found an issue, the access token generated by Google Sign In seems incomplete. Since I can't decode it

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it in the most odd way possible. The thing is that my Firebase was correct. So as a last effort I tried to make the apk of the app. It gave me a lot of errors about duplicated stuff. So I added this line to my android/app build.gradle:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'google/firestore/v1/query.proto'
    }
}
```

And it works now.